# Spyder 5.3.2 and 5.3.3 silently crash on startup

Tags: python, console, crash, spyder

I'm using pip rather than conda to manage Spyder and all my python packages. I've found that in the last couple of spyder releases, trying to run `spyder` in the console results in my mouse cursor changing to the "working" cursor for a split second, then the command executes with no output and I'm on to the next line in the console. The Spyder window never appears. Version 5.3.1 works as expected, however. I've tried updating all my packages through pip but haven't had any success. Does anyone know what I can do to further troubleshoot this? I'm at a loss, since I'm not even getting an error message.